# Eigenvectors of a matrix and its inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Show that an $n\times{n}$ invertible matrix A has the same eigenvectors as its inverse.

I can recall that the definition of a matrix and its inverse, together with the equation for the eigenvector $x$. But this proof I am not getting a concept to deal with it.

$(A-\lambda{I})x=0$

$(A^{-1}-\lambda{I})x=0$

Thank you!

Comment: @DietrichBurde Please make that an answer!

Answer (score 30):

$$Ax = \lambda x$$

$$x =\lambda A^{-1}x$$

$$\frac{1}{\lambda} x = A^{-1}x$$

Remark:

Having the same eigenvector doesn't mean the eigenvalue is the same. The equation $$(A^{-1}-\lambda I)x = 0$$ does not hold in general.